# Make MKMapView of Circular shape in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I am working on a app where I have to make Map using `MKMapView`, but with circular shape?

Any idea about this, any clue would be helpful too.

See in the screen shoot, you will get an idea what I am asking about.

See the Map in circle.

[image: See the Map in Circle]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878595/how-to-make-a-circular-uiview

Comment: @wattson please review it one more time, i just added more details.

Comment: I dont think this design changes the answer. just round the mapview, and either add the other details with overlays or as subviews

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a tricky way, but it may be you want to!

Add `QuartzCore.framework`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

//make circled shape

[yourMapView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[yourMapView.layer setCornerRadius:160.0]; //here you've to pass width of yourMapView / 2
```

Excited to see more answers!! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you do this while using satellite/aerial photographs you will violate the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/iphone/terms).

> 10 License Restrictions. Except as expressly permitted under the Terms, or unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), Google's licenses above are subject to your adherence to all of the restrictions below. Except as explicitly permitted in Section 7, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):
>
> ...
>
> 10.7 delete, obscure, or in any manner alter any warning, notice (including but not limited to any copyright or other proprietary rights notice), or link that appears in the Service or the Content;

Any circular `MKMapView` will probably obscure the copyright notice that displays with photographs.

We may expect `MKMapView` will soon change from using Google data to Apple data, but there will probably be similar text that you must not obscure.

---

With that out of the way, there are two ways you can make this work:

1. Create a `UIView` subclass with a transparent background, make its `drawRect` method draw around a circular hole, and make its `pointInside:withEvent:` method return `NO` for the same hole.  Place one of these views on top of your `MKMapView`.
2. Create a `CAShapeLayer` with an opaque circle (or any other shape) and make it the `mask` of the `MKMapView`'s own `layer`.  This will allow the circular map to appear anywhere, but it will still be possible to interact with its invisible corners.