# Round shape image view in ios

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I want to make complete round shape of `imageview` in ios for displaying profile photo of any user.

Is it possible with `layer.cornerRadius` property or need to find other solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

yes you can use `layer.cornerRadius` just dont forget to add `layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

Using QuartzCore is the best solution for you, please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878595/how-to-make-a-circular-uiview?answertab=active#tab-top), it will help you.

Note: What apply on `UIView` will apply on `UIImageView`.