# How to make round shape of any view

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiview

I just want to change the shape of view from Square to Round. As i try with cornerRadious, But it just round the corner only. As I want to make whole view as a round shape.

Comment: What do you mean by that if not the corners?

Comment: possible duplicate [How to make a circular UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878595/how-to-make-a-circular-uiview)

Comment: As, if we get any view or imageview than, buy default its in Square shape. So how can we make it as round shape without corner radious ? As if size of view is very high then its not actuly round shape with corner radious. So I just want to redraw the view and make it round shape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UIView is always rectangular. However, you can make it *look* round (or any shape at all, actually) with a mask. To do so, make a UIImage which is a black circle (in a transparent background). Now take the CGImage of that UIImage and make it the contents of a CALayer. Finally, set that CALayer as the `mask` of the layer of your view.

Let us suppose that your view is 100 x 100. Then (not tested, but should be pretty much right):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100,100), NO, 0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(c, CGRectMake(0,0,100,100));
UIImage* maskim = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CALayer* mask = [CALayer new];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
mask.contents = (id)maskim.CGImage;

view.layer.mask = mask;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this (i.e., mask a UIView so it appears circular) in Storyboard, or does it have to be done programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can make rounded border with width of border of any control in this way:-

```
CALayer * l1 = [viewPopup layer];
[l1 setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l1 setCornerRadius:5.0];

// You can even add a border
[l1 setBorderWidth:5.0];
[l1 setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
```

Just replace `viewPopup` with your control. 
 

**Note:-** Don't forget to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
[roundView.layer setCornerRadius:50.0f];
[roundView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[roundView.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
[roundView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[roundView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[roundView.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[roundView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```

**Note:-** roundView is your view that you want to round.

I hope it helps you. Thanks