# How to crop an image which is coming inside circle in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, crop

I am working on a project where I need to show an screen same as below[image]

Here the image should be cropped which is visible only in the circle. I have tried image masking as below. But it always crop in square.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage1:(UIImage *) image withMask:(UIImage *) mask
{
CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
CGImageRef maskReference = mask.CGImage;

CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
                                         CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference),
                                         NULL, // Decode is null
                                         YES // Should interpolate
                                         );

CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask);
CGImageRelease(imageMask);

UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

return maskedImage;
}
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16475824/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the demo to scale and crop image circle.[Circle Image Crop](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper)

for Masking your image in to circle as below cede.

```
//Masking the image
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(hiddenView.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0); //In this I have take screenshot of a hiddenView that I have added from IB with a background color anything( in this case it's orange). 
//Replace this hiddenView object with your object of whom you want to take screenshot.

[hiddenView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  //Similarly replace hiddenView here with your object.

UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData*theImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 );
imgView.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:theImageData];  //I placed a UIImageView to check and place the screenshot into it as Image ,simply to cross check if I'm getting a right screenshot or not.
 //So you could also remove this line after your have verified that your getting right screen shot.
```

Comment: It is not returning the circle image

Comment: I have mentioned above

Comment: See, you need to pass your circle object in place of hiddenView then you would get your screen shot as I have tested and it had worked for me when I wanted a screen shot of a particular object.