# How can we round the UIImageView using autolayouts

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project have added image on my tableview cell, for this I have tried some code but that's not working, what did I do here wrong?

Here my main requirement is I want to round that image (as like circle format).

My code:

```
 Personimage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
   Personimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ram.jpeg"];
   Personimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   [Cell.contentView addSubview:Personimage];

   //Applying autolayouts

    NSDictionary * viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(Personimage)

     [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Personimage(80)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];

        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[Personimage(80)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];
}

-(Void)ViewDidAppear
{
  Personimage.layer.cornerRadius = Personimage.frame.size.width / 2;
  Personimage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
  Personimage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  Personimage.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

After applying auto-layouts i have kept image"round" properties in viewDidAppear method but still it's not working what did i do wrong here? please help me someone

Comment: What's not working? What happens when you run this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storyboard and autolayout: how make a circular image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182206/storyboard-and-autolayout-how-make-a-circular-image)

Comment: set personimage.clipdToBounds = YES ; and set imageview frame before assigning a image to it ...

Comment: you will have to import `QuartzCore.h` in your class for `cornerRadius` property to work

Comment: Do you want swift code or obj-c code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to round the `UIImageView`

```
 imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.width / 2;
 imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: no that's not working and i have already tried this in my above code

Comment: It is working. You should put it in the right place like `viewDidAppear` for example. ;) You should use the half width of your `UIImage`, not `UIImageView`, because it will be `CGSizeZero` before it could be layed out by AutoLayout. You could still use it like this, but as I said, put the code in the right place, after AutoLayout is done its job.

Comment: this works fine for me.., thanks Vidhi for sharing the answer

Answer (score 0):

The property clipsToBounds is a `Bool` value, change its value from YES to true will work.

Have fun with Swift!