# Is it possible to make a circular NSButton?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I am trying to create a custom shape `NSButton`. In particular I am trying to make a round button, using a custom image. I've found [a tutorial](http://www.iosinsight.com/circular-uibutton-with-swift/) on the creation of custom `UIButton` and tried to adapt it to NSButton. But there's a huge problem. `clipsToBounds` seems to be iOS only(

Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainButton: NSButton!
    var size = 32

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureButton()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func configureButton()
    {
        mainButton.wantsLayer = true
        mainButton.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy.OnSetNeedsDisplay
        mainButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 0.5 * mainButton.bounds.size.width
        mainButton.layer?.borderColor = NSColor(red:0.0/255.0, green:122.0/255.0, blue:255.0/255.0, alpha:1).CGColor as CGColorRef
        mainButton.layer?.borderWidth = 2.0
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make a circular NSButton? Can you suggest anything on replacing `clipsToBounds`?

Because here is what I was able to get so far:

[image]

Comment: "clipsToBounds seems to be iOS only" But CALayer `masksToBounds` is not. The difference is merely because an NSView is not automatically layer-backed, whereas a UIView is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't play around with corner radius. A circle doesn't have corners. To make the button appear as a circle, mask the button's `layer` to a circle.

Comment: Even though you're on OS X, the principle is no different from this iOS answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16475824/341994 After all, Core Graphics is Core Graphics, and CALayer is CALayer, regardless of which platform you're on.

Comment: Except of course, masking will break the focus ring, and accessibility.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Very interesting point. I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 8):

NSButton is a subclass of NSView, so all methods in NSView, such as drawRect(_:), are also available in NSButton.

So create a new **Button.swift** which you draw your custom layout

```
import Cocoa

class Button: NSButton {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
        let path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: dirtyRect)
        NSColor.green.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

}
```

[image]

Great Tutorial [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1). It is iOS , but quite similar!

Comment: The code draws the circle but the remaining portion of the rect has still out there. It's because of calling the super.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the radius based upon the width of the button.  By the look of your screenshot, the button is not a square when you start, so rounding the corners cannot create a circle.