# How to make UIImageView Circular in all iOS devices using AutoLayout and want to increase its height and width using Autolayout

Tags: ios

I am using the below code...What AutoLayout Constraints need

```
_imgViewProfile.layer.cornerRadius = _imgViewProfile.frame.size.height/2;
    [_imgViewProfile setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: _imgViewProfile must be equal width and height to make it circular

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
 imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"];
 imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0 ;
 imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these links
[How to make a circular UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878595/how-to-make-a-circular-uiview)
[How To Create Circular Profile Picture and Rounded Corner Image](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/)

Many examples shared with good detail level. In nutshell you would be doing this:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```